# What is meant by a ValueError: Invalid NPM block in import when trying to run brownie compile?

Tags: python, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, brownie

I am trying to test and replicate in my local machine the FundMe.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.6

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

contract FundMe {
    
    using SafeMathChainlink for uint256;
    
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address[] public funders;
    address public owner;
    
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function fund() public payable {
        uint minimumUSD = 50 * 10 ** 18;
        require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minimumUSD, "You need to spend more ETH! reminder by: Marco Rado");
        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        funders.push(msg.sender);
    }
    
    function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
        return priceFeed.version();
    }
    
    function getPrice() public view returns(uint256) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
        (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer * 10000000000);
        //4,143.080000000000000000
    }
    
    function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1000000000000000000;
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }
    
    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    
    function withdraw() payable onlyOwner public {
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
        for (uint256 funderIndex=0; funderIndex < funders.length; funderIndex++) {
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        funders = new address[](0);
    }
    
}
```

with a
brownie-config.yaml

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.2.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.2.0'
```

but when I do compile using: brownie compile

I got this ValueError:

marco@MarcoD2-5212019 MINGW64 ~/Documents/Blockchain/Smart Contracts University/demos/brownie_fund_me (main)
$ brownie compile
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.16.3 - Python development framework for Ethereum

File "C:\Users\marco.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie_cli_*main*_.py", line 64, in main
importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
File "C:\Users\marco.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie_cli\compile.py", line 50, in main
proj = project.load()
File "C:\Users\marco.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 745, in load
return Project(name, project_path)
File "C:\Users\marco.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 180, in **init**
self.load()
File "C:\Users\marco.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 235, in load
self._compile(changed, self._compiler_config, False)
File "C:\Users\marco.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 102, in *compile
optimizer=compiler_config["solc"].get("optimizer", None),
File "C:\Users\marco.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\compiler_*init**.py", line 105, in compile_and_format
find_solc_versions(solc_sources, install_needed=True, silent=silent)
File "C:\Users\marco.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\compiler\solidity.py", line 150, in find_solc_versions
pragma_specs[path] = sources.get_pragma_spec(source, path)
File "C:\Users\marco.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\sources.py", line 218, in get_pragma_spec
return NpmSpec(pragma_string)
File "C:\Users\marco.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\semantic_version\base.py", line 618, in **init**
self.clause = self._parse_to_clause(expression)
File "C:\Users\marco.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\semantic_version\base.py", line 1225, in _parse_to_clause
return cls.Parser.parse(expression)
File "C:\Users\marco.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\semantic_version\base.py", line 1265, in parse
raise ValueError("Invalid NPM block in %r: %r" % (expression, block))
ValueError: Invalid NPM block in '^0.6.6 import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol"': 'import'

marco@MarcoD2-5212019 MINGW64 ~/Documents/Blockchain/Smart Contracts University/demos/brownie_fund_me (main)

[bash terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrM4d.png)

Comment: You are missing the semi-colon on your very first statement.

Comment: Could you also copy paste your error instead of a screenshot?